# React component props don't get updated with redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Button.js component

```
    import React from "react"
import "../styles/button.scss"
import store from "../index"

class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.buttonTextChanger()
    }

    buttonTextChanger() {
        this.buttonText = "MainPage" === this.props.state.page ? "Az adatokhoz" : "A főoldalra"
    }


    logger = (actualPage) => {
        this.props.onButtonClick(actualPage)
        console.log("state from store before textchange", store.getState())
        console.log("state from props before textchange", this.props.state)
        this.buttonTextChanger()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="container">
                <button className="learn-more" onClick = {() => this.logger(this.props.state.page)}>
                    <span className="circle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <span className="icon arrow"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span className="button-text">{this.buttonText}</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Button
```

My problem is that the component's props don't seem to be updated with the redux store. The redux store updates to the correct value after the onClick function runs, mapStateToProps also runs with the correct state and still after these if I try to log the state from the prop I get the old value. If I do the same log in the render function before returning the JSX I get the correct state from props and I can't get my head around why it isn't updated immediately after the redux store is.
So if I modify the code to the following it works as expected:

```
logger = (actualPage) => {
        this.props.onButtonClick(actualPage)
        console.log("state from store before textchange", store.getState())

    }

    render() { 
        console.log("state from props before textchange", this.props.state)
        this.buttonTextChanger()  
        return (
            <div id="container">
                <button className="learn-more" onClick = {() => this.logger(this.props.state.page)}>
                    <span className="circle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <span className="icon arrow"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span className="button-text">{this.buttonText}</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Reducer function

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux"

export const changePageReducer = (state = {page : "MainPage"}, action) => {
    if (action.type === "CHANGE_PAGE")
        if (action.payload !== state.page) {
            return action.payload
        }

    return state.page
}

export const combinedReducers = combineReducers({page : changePageReducer})
```

Button container

```
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Button from "../components/Button"
import changePage from "../actions/changePage"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("az injectelt state", state)
    return {state}
} 

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onButtonClick : (page) => {
            switch (page) {
                case "MainPage":
                    dispatch(changePage("DataPage"))
                    break
                case "DataPage":
                    dispatch(changePage("MainPage"))
                    break
                default:
                    dispatch(changePage("MainPage"))
            }
        }
    }
}

const ChangePageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Button)

export default ChangePageContainer
```

But I'd like to extract the buttonTextChanger() function call from the render function and call it on click.

TLDR:
the problem:

```
logger = (actualPage) => {
  console.log("prop state value before dispatch", this.props.state)
  console.log("store value before dispatch", store.getState())
  this.props.onButtonClick(actualPage)
  console.log("prop state value after dispatch", this.props.state)
  console.log("store value after dispatch", store.getState())
}
```

also there is a console.log in the mapStateToProps function to see the state that gets passed to props.
This yields:

```
prop state value before dispatch {page: "MainPage"}
store value before dispatch {page: "MainPage"}
state when mapStateToProps function called {page: "DataPage"}
store value after dispatch {page: "DataPage"}
prop state value after dispatch {page: "MainPage"}
```

So the prop doesn't get updated.

Comment: Can you post your reducer function also?

Comment: for that purpose you need to use componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: so basically you need to play with data that you are updating to store right ?

Comment: yes, I updated the question so it contains more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can't wrap your head around why `this.props.state` isn't updated even after calling the dispatcher?

You see,
**Redux is entirely built on functional programming**, and now with hooks, React is also fully moving towards Functional Programming, hell even JavaScript was originally built as Functional Programming.

One thing that's entirely different from OOP and the coolest thing too is that, **There are no mutations in Functional Programming.** There isn't. Vanilla Redux is fully FP having only pure functions - functions without side effects. That's why you need Redux Saga or other library for making API calls - unpure functions.

Cutting to the chase,

```js
logger = (actualPage) => {
  // here,
  // actualPage => new value
  // this.props.state => old value
  // they will remain as such throughout this function


  console.log("prop state value before dispatch", this.props.state)
  console.log("store value before dispatch", store.getState())
  this.props.onButtonClick(actualPage)

  // even if you update the Redux Store, 
  // `this.props.state` will still have the old value
  // since this value will not be mutated

  console.log("prop state value after dispatch", this.props.state)
  console.log("store value after dispatch", store.getState())
}
```

*Then what about `store.getState()`, their values are updated*, you may ask.

Notice how it's not `store.getState` but instead `store.getState()`? Yes it is a function instead of a value. Whenever you call them, they return the latest value and there isn't any mutations in them. In your case, the second time you are calling after dispatching the action, hence you get the latest value. It's not mutation, `store.getState()` just grabbed the latest value there is and returned it to you. `logger()` will get the new values once that first call is over, then the cycle repeats again.

Action dispatchers will create a new `state` from the old `state`, that's why you can time travel in Redux DevTools.

Again recapping

```js
logger = (actualPage) => {
  // old value
  console.log("prop state value before dispatch", this.props.state)
  // old value
  console.log("store value before dispatch", store.getState())

  // new value
  this.props.onButtonClick(actualPage)
  // redux would be updated with new values by now

  // but still old value - no mutation
  console.log("prop state value after dispatch", this.props.state)
  // new value
  console.log("store value after dispatch", store.getState())
}
```

Comment: I'm using react-redux. I should have posted more of my code so I corrected my mistake.

Comment: Since you were using `store.getState()` as Vanilla JS, I assumed you weren't using react-redux. Now Updated my answer

Comment: I only used store.getState() to check if the store gets updated and it does. I need to run the function before the first render so I beleive I can't use componentDidMount because it runs after render. I can use the componentWillMount lifecycle method but that still doesn't solve my problem that the props don't get updated on clicking the button only the store does.

Comment: I can only see console logs for before update not after update. Make the question precise, and add the methods you tried